# Why is there an Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed in my code?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting an "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed error" for the below code block. I am creating a new instance of connection for each request and closing them off in the finally block.

```
public int getUserIdBasedOnAlias(String alias){
    int i=0;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt=null;
    DBHelper dbh=new DBHelper();
    java.sql.Connection con=dbh.getConnection();
    try{
        cstmt=con.prepareCall("{call sp_GetUserIdBasedOnAlias(?)}");
        cstmt.setString(1,alias);
        rs=cstmt.executeQuery();  
        while(rs.next()){  // *** ERROR IS HERE ***
                i=rs.getInt("UserId");                                               
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            dbh.close(rs, cstmt, con);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Below is the code in the DBHelper class

```
public  Connection getConnection() {

    //Loading JDBC Driver Class
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,userName,pwd);
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}



public void close(ResultSet rs, CallableStatement cstmt, Connection con) throws SQLException {
    try {
        try {
            if (rs!=null) rs.close();
        } finally {
            if (cstmt!=null) cstmt.close();
        }
    } finally {
        if (con!=null) con.close();
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkClosed(ResultSet.java:666)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:7274)
  at COM.FRMC.PKG.Employee.getUserIdBasedOnAlias(Employee.java:101)
```

Procedure Declaration:

```
Delimiter $$
Create Procedure sp_GetUserIdBasedOnAlias
(
in aliasname nvarchar(50)
)
Begin

Select 1 as UserId;
End$$
Delimiter ;
```

This is the working code:

```
public int getUserIdBasedOnAlias(String alias) throws SQLException{
        int i=0;
        DBHelper dbh=new DBHelper();
        ResultSet rs=null;
        CallableStatement cstmt=null;
        java.sql.Connection con=dbh.getConnectionToFRMC_RiskAssessment();
        try{
            CallableStatement ct = con.prepareCall("{CALL sp_GetUserIdBasedOnAlias(?)}");
            ct.setString(1,alias);
            ct.execute();
            ResultSet rs1=ct.getResultSet();
            while(rs1.next()){
                i=rs1.getInt(1);
            }

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                dbh.close(rs, cstmt, con);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly in the code do you get the error?

Comment: Its in the rs.next() line ...java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkClosed(ResultSet.java:666)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:7274)
 at COM.FRMC.PKG.Employee.getUserIdBasedOnAlias(Employee.java:101)

Comment: Does your stored procedure return a result set at all?

Comment: Yes it does return an integer value irrespective of parameter value...

Comment: There is a difference between a returned **value** and a returned **`ResultSet`**. Can you show the declaration of your stored procedure? And please, no code in the comments. Add the information by editing your question.

Comment: I am just not able to insert the SQL code in the question, its giving some error that its not properly formatted ... tried different ways but its still the same issue ...Sorry for the trouble ...

Comment: You are supposed to paste it into the question, and then select it again and click on the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Thank you RealSkeptic ... I have included the procedure code...

Comment: Are you by any chance using the connection from multiple threads?

Comment: It could also be that you need to use `{?=call sp_GetUserIdBasedOnAlias(?)}`, use `execute()` and `getInt(1)` (or maybe `getInt(2)`) on the `CallableStatement`, but I am not that familiar with stored procedures in MySQL. You may also need to use `setString(2, alias)` now, as this parameter has moved to the second position.

Comment: Hi Mark..I am not so sure about the multiple threading part ... I am using a new instance of Connection object for query execution and closing it in the finally block ... Can you please further clarify on that ?

Comment: Guys... I am still stuck in this problem ... Please help !!!

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this.  Your code ran fine, even when I modified it to run on 100 threads. I'm on Windows 8.1 x64, Java 8 x64 1.8.0_45, MySQL 5.5, MySQL connector JAR 5.1.18.  The only thing I can think of is that the connection between your Java program and the database is getting closed. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9562#c23066

Comment: Hi Luke, Thank you so much for looking into it ... Even I have used similar code before and it worked everytime ... Btw, I did some changes in the code (updated in the post) and its working again (though I have no idea how) ...

Comment: `con` appears to be a data member of the `DBHelper` class. That means it's available to be closed by other means. It's a bug. It should be a local variable only, everywhere where used. The fiddling around you did inside the `getUserIdBasedOnAlias()` method hasn't actually fixed anything: something else has changed.